# Manipulating curves with python

Tags: python, math

So I am using this python script to create the curves you see in the image. Without going into detail about the real usage of this, my question is:

-Is there a way to create the blue and yellow curves without the linear values (red curve) ? Based on the blue line "formula" ( **sin(x*90*pi/180)** )

-Also, do I really need to create a for loop and append values like I do in the script or is there a more "clean" way of creating the array of values in one line?

In the end I just want to make sure that with my limited knowledge of maths and python I am not making it more complex than it's needed. Thank you.

[image: curves]

```
### RED CURVE ###

linearValues = []

for i in range(0,91):
    linearValues.append( float(  float(i)/float(90) ) )

linearValues.reverse()



### BLUE CURVE ###

blueCurveValues = []

for i in range(0,91):
    blueCurveValues.append( math.sin(linearValues[i]*90*math.pi/180) )



### YELLOW CURVE ###

yellowCurveValues = []

for i in range(0,91):
    yellowCurveValues.append( float( linearValues[i]-(blueCurveValues[i]-linearValues[i]) ) )
```

Comment: You do more arithmetic than needed. Your equation for the blue line has 90xπ/180 in the sin term, so the 90 cancels out, and you really have π*x/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, you should cast `int`s to `float`s before dividing (if you don’t want integer division).  And then you only need the cast when you’re dividing two `int`s, which only happens for `linearValues` (and you’d only need `float(i)/90` or `i/float(90)`, not three casts).  But in Python 3 (or using `from __future__ import division`), this is done automatically, and you don’t need any calls to `float`.  I’ve removed them.

The Pythonic way for creating your lists is called “list comprehension”.  Translating exactly what you’ve written, this would be:

```
linearValues = [ i/90 for i in range(90,-1,-1) ]
blueCurveValues = [ math.sin(linearValues[i]*90*math.pi/180) for i in range(91) ]
yellowCurveValues = [ linearValues[i]-(blueCurvevalues[i]-linearValues[i] for i in range(91) ]
```

If you want to not have the linearValues calculated, the obvious thing to do is simply replace `linearValues[i]` with `i/90` every time.  This would simplify your blue values formula, but only marginally so your yellow.  At the least, you may want to consider changing `90*math.pi/180` to `math.pi/2` (or `(i/90*90*math.pi/180)` to `(i*math.pi/180)`).  But this is still using the red curve, just under the hood.

Another option for creating your lists would be `map`:

```
linearValues = map(lambda x:x/90,range(90,-1,-1))
blueCurveValues = map(lambda x:math.sin(x*90*math.pi/180),linearValues)
yellowCurveValues = map(lambda x,y:x-(y-x),linearValues,blueCurveValues)
```

`map` and `lambda` is generally harder to read than a list comprehension, but a shorter formula is generally easier.  So red should probably be a list comprehension.  Blue and yellow would depend on your preference.